# middleware('auth') doesn't work when i changed default auth table

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-middleware, laravel-8

So i changed config/auth.php to change default auth table from user to accounts like this :

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'accounts',
],
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'accounts',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'accounts',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'accounts' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Akun::class,
    ],

],
```

i have changed App\Akun Model configuration same as App\User Model :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Akun extends Authenticatable
{
use HasFactory;
protected $table = 'accounts';

protected $fillable = [
    'nip',
    'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
}
```

And My Login system is working too. It can return back if the NIP or Password wrong and give error message too. Here my login code:

```
function checklogin(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request,[
        'nip'   => 'required',
        'password'  => 'required'
    ]);
    $akun_data = array(
        'nip' =>  $request->get('nip'),
        'password'  =>  $request->get('password')
    );
    if(Auth::attempt($akun_data)){
        return redirect('login/successlogin');
    }else{
        return back()->with('pesan','NIP atau Password salah');
    }
}
```

it was working and return correctly to login/successlogin and run the code in there. But when i tried to add middleware('auth') to the route of login/succeslogin , it'll always return back to login page even when i gave the correct nip and password

```
Route::get('/login/successlogin',[LoginController::class, 'successlogin'])->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this, My way to change default auth table is correct. But I forgot to add id column there. just add this code in your New Default Auth Table Migration

```
$table->id();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a new guard that will be for your accounts table and call it 'accounts' and then in your routes i.e. you can provide route grouping by guard i.e.

```php
Route::middleware('auth:accounts')->group(function () { ...other protected routes... });
```

Comment: i have added 
` 'accounts' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'accounts',
        ],`
and 
`Route::middleware('auth:accounts')->group(function () { 
    Route::get('/login/successlogin',[LoginController::class, 'successlogin']);
});` but it's still return back to login page .